# VBA excel: how to iterate through a column and change offset column based on condition

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to change cells 6 columns to the right of my iteration. The vba below does not seem to come up with any errors, but when I run the Sub, nothing updates. Any ideas?

```
Sub RemoveDate()

Dim state
Dim dat
Dim cell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long


Sheets("RawData").Select

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'If cell in column J is = state then change the cell 6 columns to right

For Each cell In Range("J1" & LastRow).Cells
    state = cell.Value
    dat = cell.Offset(0, 6).Value

    If state = "Pending" Then
        dat = "TBD"
    ElseIf state = "Under Review" Then
        dat = "TBD"
    ElseIf state = "BRD Refinement" Then
        dat = "TBD"
    ElseIf state = "On Hold" Then
        dat = "TBD"
    End If
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Surprised `Range("J1" & LastRow).Cells` didn't throw an error. I think you meant `Range("J" & LastRow).Cells`? Which is really only one cell?

Comment: `Dim dat as Range`.  Then `Set dat = cell.Offset(0, 6)`.

Comment: @findwindow `Range("J1" & LastRow)` should be `Range("J1", .Range("J" & LastRow))`

Comment: Ahhh that makes more sense.

Comment: Or `Range("J1:J" & LastRow)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because there was more than one item wrong, this combines mine and FindWindow's comments:

```
Sub RemoveDate()

Dim state
Dim dat As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long


Sheets("RawData").Select

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'If cell in column J is = state then change the cell 6 columns to right

For Each cell In Range("J1", Range("J" & LastRow)).Cells
    state = cell.Value
    Set dat = cell.Offset(0, 6)

    If state = "Pending" Then
        dat = "TBD"
    ElseIf state = "Under Review" Then
        dat = "TBD"
    ElseIf state = "BRD Refinement" Then
        dat = "TBD"
    ElseIf state = "On Hold" Then
        dat = "TBD"
    End If
Next


End Sub
```

With `dat = cell.Offset(0, 6).Value` you are setting the variable dat to the contents of the cell.  Then with the if statements you replace the value in the variable alone not the cell.

By making the variable a range, and using the `Set` keyword, it referes to the cell itself and replaces what ever is in the cell with the value set in your if statement.

Just a side note look into Select Case, it is easier when using multiple elseif's.  Replace the whole loop with this:

```
For Each cell In Range("J1", Range("J" & LastRow)).Cells
   Select Case cell.Value
        'because all the values result in the same outcome
        Case "Pending", "Under Review", "BRD Refinement", "On Hold"
            cell.Offset(0, 6) = "TBD"
        Case Else
    End Select        
Next
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! Also thanks for the Select Case suggestion, that looks much better.

Comment: @Scap Glad to help.  Please accept as correct, by selecting the green check mark under the down arrow.

Answer (score 2):

why not this way:

```
Sub RemoveDate()
  Dim state As String, cell As Variant, LastRow As Long
  LastRow = Sheets("RawData").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  For Each cell In Sheets("RawData").Range("J1:J" & LastRow).Cells
    state = cell.Value
    If state = "Pending" Or state = "Under Review" Or state = "BRD Refinement" Or state = "On Hold" Then
      cell.Offset(0, 6).Value = "TBD"
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

when doing it for a lot of cells, it may be slow, so i'd do it more like this way:

```
Sub RemoveDate()
  Dim getRng As Variant, putRng As Variant, i As Long
  i = Sheets("RawData").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  Set getRng = Sheets("RawData").Range("J1:J" & i).Value
  Set putRng = Sheets("RawData").Range("P1:P" & i).Value 

  While i > 1
    If getRng(i, 1) = "Pending" Or getRng(i, 1) = "Under Review" Or getRng(i, 1) = "BRD Refinement" Or getRng(i, 1) = "On Hold" Then
      putRng(i, 1) = "TBD"
    End If
    i = i - 1
  Wend
  Sheets("RawData").Range("P1:P" & Ubound(putRng)).Value = putRng
End Sub
```

if there also formulas in `P` then better replace `.Value` with `.Formula`.
the second code simply puts all the values of the range to check and change in to variables. then uses `i` as address to get the values in the variables to compare/change it (from the last item to the first). Which is much faster then doing it with the real cells. however, your `For Each ...` does the same in the first way, but the need of the `.Offset` kinda kills it again.  as last action it puts the whole range of the outputvalue back to your sheet. doing this for lots of cells in one step, is also much faster then doing this only for some cells one after another. this way it also overwrites the cells which havent changed with their old value (as a funny fact: this is still faster than leaving them out)